# Does a (square) full rank matrix have identical column and row spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

Say we have a **full rank matrix A** (i.e., the rows are linearly independent and the same is true for columns). Since using the basic procedures of swapping, scalar multiplication, and addition, we can arrive at a row (or column) reduced echelon form which is the identity matrix (i.e., $rref(A)=I=cref(A)$, for any A that is full rank), it stands to reason that the columns and rows of A are just different basis for the same space (i.e., $span(A)=span(A^T)$).

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, and that space is the whole vector space $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Karl . That seems obvious, after some thought. I would add that any square full rank matrix represents a change of basis from the basis defined by its columns to the canonical basis.